# Calculate cosine with sum of addends

Tags: c

Need some help with a task from my homework.
They gave us a series to calculate cosine, which is:
Σ(-1)^ix^2i/(2i)!
And the task is to implement this in C program by writing a function that takes angle x, and calculate it's cosine. The series should continue summing until the next addend in the series is less then 1.0e-6 (0.000001). I did this and it works good only for small numbers, if I put big numbers as angle, the program get stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.141592

double my_cos(double angle);

int main() {
    double angle, radian,  my_res, their_res;

    printf("Please type a number... \n");
    scanf("%lf", &angle);

    radian = angle * (PI/180);


    my_res = my_cos(radian); /* result from my custom cosine function */
    their_res = cos(radian); /* result from the cos function located in the library math.h */

    printf("My result is: %f \nMath.h library result is: %f \n", my_res, their_res);

    return 0;
}
```

.

```
#include <math.h>
#define ACCURACY 1.0e-6

long factorial(int x);


double my_cos(double angle){
    int i = 0;
    double sum = 0,  next_addend;

    do {
        next_addend = pow(-1, (i+1)) * pow(angle, 2*(i+1)) / factorial(2*(i+1));
        sum += pow(-1, i) * pow(angle, 2*i) / factorial(2*i);

        i++;
    } while ( ACCURACY < fabs(next_addend) );

    return sum;
}

/* return the factorial of a given value */
long factorial(int x){
    if ( x == 0 ) {
        return 1;
    }

    return(x * factorial(x - 1));
}
```

If I run the program and insert 45:
[image]

But if I insert 300, the program is just "waiting":
[image]

I guess it related somehow to the factorial function?
I will really appreciate your help..

Comment: Well, sure enough, the greater the `x`, the greater the number of iterations.

Comment: Did you run it on a debugger to see where the eternal loop is and why?

Comment: It is very likely a problem with the factorial function as you say, but to be *sure* you should use a debugger to step through the code and find out. Even if it takes a long time and is tedious and boring, being able to use a debugger is a crucial skill for any programmer, even on a hobby-level.

Comment: If you do some calculations involving the Taylor series (this is the formula you've been given), you'll see that the accuracy depends on the number of elements in the sequence, and vice versa: the more elements, the greater the accuracy, but at some point, you'd need so many elements that the factorial a will become huge and totally not representable even with `unsigned long long`. But you know that the cosine is _a periodic function_...

Comment: your `factorial` in a loop like that... I would try to pre-compute whatever many factorial that I need and keep them in an array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on whether `sizeof(long)` is 4 or 8 on your system you can only calculate 12! or 20! inside a `long`. Also, calculating multiple `pow` at every iteration is very inefficient.

For a better solution, try to find out how to calculate the `next_addend` if you know the previous addend (hint: calculate their ratio on a piece of paper).

Comment: So, even if the OP could compute 20!, they'd be able to represent values of `x` such that `fabs(x) < 4.1620398187437662` only as `fabs(x) < root(factorial(i) * accuracy, i)`.

Comment: @ForceBru sure, but you should never explitly calculate any factorial here at all. About your comment on exploiting the periodicity: One should definitely do that for an actual implementation, but then one should also use min-max approximations instead of Taylor polynomials.